# Change full height navbar-item background color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. And I want to replicate this page's design:

https://www.stickermule.com/custom-stickers

For a more clear idea, I'm using a red bg to ilustrate what I need.

I could change the navbar item background color to red, but there is a gap at the top and at the bottom.

How can I solve this?

[image]

CSS Code:

```
li.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Etiquetas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magnetos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empaques</a>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>-->


            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LogIn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registro</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Solution by works only when adding nav tag :

```
nav.navbar {padding: 0 1rem;}
```

Instead of just:

```
.navbar {padding: 0 1rem;}
```

Why?

I'm calling my css file like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'gallito_app/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Head content:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link href="{% static 'gallito_app/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
```

Comment: In your header are calling your custom CSS link,  before or after bootstrap CSS link ... can you show your header

Comment: @cool-man please, see update.

Comment: If i get it right your custom css is at '<link href="{% static 'gallito_app/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">' you should put it at the end so it will override bootstrap original setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also alter the height of the navbar

```
.navbar {padding: 0 1rem;}
```

if you want to keep the same height add

```
.navbar .nav-item{padding:1rem 1rem}
```

Comment: ty. it works, but please see my update and please make an explanation of what you code does.

Comment: the first line remove the top and bottom gap from the container '.navbar' .5rem  and the second line add the same value to the 'a' child, originaly '.5rem 1rem' when add the .5rem removed from the container give '1rem 1rem'